# dicom dcmmkdir command line

Tags: command-line, dicom

I am creating Dicom Dir and I am working DCMMKDIR exe. I have my inputfiles in C:\DICOMFiles, DCMMKDIR is in C:\DicomEXE and I want Output to be in C:\DICOMCDDIR

could you please guide me what I should give arguments to DCMMKDIR.

Answer (score 1):

Which dcmmkdir are you using? If it is the one from dcmtk all options can be seen here: http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/dcmmkdir.html

Comment: thank you, I am referring the same.But not understanding. Could please explain and post the command.

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

> dcmmkdir --input-directory
>   c:/my_input/images/ --output-file
>   c:/DICOMDIR